# Strange deadlock in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, deadlock, irq

I normally think that deadlock could be a conflict of acquiring two different locks at two different threads (CPUs) while holding the other lock each other.

But, the lockdep in linux kernel tells me otherwise:

Here is the first one:

```
[  340.052197]  [<ffffffff81405448>] lock_irq_serial+0x14/0x16
[  340.058529]  [<ffffffff8136cb7e>] tell_me_store+0x178/0x60a
[  340.064858]  [<ffffffff8136a9be>] kobj_attr_store+0xf/0x19
[  340.070641]  [<ffffffff811e0d55>] sysfs_kf_write+0x39/0x3b
[  340.076423]  [<ffffffff811e01ee>] kernfs_fop_write+0xd5/0x11e
[  340.082475]  [<ffffffff81188c0d>] vfs_write+0xb7/0x18f
[  340.087890]  [<ffffffff81189470>] SyS_write+0x42/0x86
[  340.093213]  [<ffffffff816eff79>] ia32_do_call+0x13/0x13
```

where lock_irq_serial is a spin_lock. This lock is also used inside irq_work infrastructure.

The other part is:

```
[  344.135856]  [<ffffffff8110be77>] generic_exec_single+0x108/0x120
[  344.142277]  [<ffffffff8109071e>] ? leave_mm+0xbc/0xbc
[  344.147691]  [<ffffffff8109071e>] ? leave_mm+0xbc/0xbc
[  344.153104]  [<ffffffff8109071e>] ? leave_mm+0xbc/0xbc
[  344.158525]  [<ffffffff8110bf46>] smp_call_function_single+0x88/0xa4
[  344.165225]  [<ffffffff8110c0ff>] smp_call_function_many+0xf7/0x21a
[  344.171829]  [<ffffffff8109071e>] ? leave_mm+0xbc/0xbc
[  344.177249]  [<ffffffff810908a2>] native_flush_tlb_others+0x29/0x2b
[  344.183853]  [<ffffffff81090a4a>] flush_tlb_mm_range+0xed/0x146
[  344.190094]  [<ffffffff811769fc>] change_protection+0x126/0x581
[  344.196336]  [<ffffffff81176fa9>] mprotect_fixup+0x152/0x1cb
[  344.202299]  [<ffffffff811771a1>] SyS_mprotect+0x17f/0x20e
[  344.208078]  [<ffffffff816eff79>] ia32_do_call+0x13/0x13
```

where I don't do anything up there.
I think there could be issue with spin-locking in irq_work and also locking it in other place (such as sysfs writing). Could anybody explain further details why this is a deadlock scenario?

Comment: Show the entire message.

Comment: What is `tell_me_store` and `lock_irq_serial`? There is no such thing in Linux Kernel. Also, regarding "acquiring two different locks" - not necessary. Deadlock may include N threads and M locks, 2 threads and 2 locks is just a simplest case of it.

Comment: Try to enable [lockdep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892822/how-to-use-lockdep-feature-in-linux-kernel-for-deadlock-detection) feature in your kernel. It should show you more specific message (in runtime). You can also run `coccicheck` on suspicious sources to detect deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock can happens in single core.

1) normal kernel context is taking "spin_lock"

2) interrupt handler is taking the same "spin_lock".

Then, when kernel context is holding the lock, if interrupts comes, what will happen? Not necessarily multiple locks and multiple threads. (actually, multiple contexts are engaged.)

By looking at the backtrace, it's hard to understand what's going on. Typically, backtrace at deadlock situation is not showing who is holding the lock.

Suggesting is, enable kernel deadlock detection config option and see what will happen.