# How do I know a spin lock or other locks like mutex or semaphore is already acquired in a program. but not released?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, multiprocessing, kernel-module

In my project, program flow always hangs at one place.
When I debugged it, I found a few complex locking mechanisms are used.
Kind of spinlock and mutex.

How can I identify that number of spin locks or other locks like mutex, semaphore is already acquired in the program, but not released respectively?

Comment: Do you want this feature only for **debugging purposes**? If so, rebuild your kernel with `DEBUG_MUTEXES` and `DEBUG_SPINLOCKS` configuration options enabled. With that options, the kernel itself will assert many things about mutexes and spinlocks usage. E.g., it will check that no thread is terminated while it helds a mutex.

Comment: LOCKDEP is good to have enabled as well.

Comment: "complex locking mechanism" should be a red flag. If your locking is so complex that it's leading to deadlocks, it's likely that you need to re-think your synchronization scheme.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21440835/1485176